# Unable to use CSS properties in React

Tags: reactjs

I used `npx create-react-app` to setup the work space. Then, I deleted all the files in **src** directory to write everything from scratch. I created a few components one of which is as follows:

```
import React from "react";

function AwesomeHeader() {
  return (
    <span>
      <input type="checkbox"></input>
      <p className="span-class">Do you like this Awesome header ?</p>
    </span>
  );
}

export default AwesomeHeader;
```

Now, My App.js file has the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import AwesomeHeader from "./components/AwesomeHeader";
import AwesomeFooter from "./components/AwesomeFooter";
import MainBody from "./components/MainBody";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AwesomeHeader />
      <MainBody />
      <AwesomeFooter />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now, the index.js file is having the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Issue is that when I apply any styling to the components in my **style.css** file, nothing happens to the styling of the components. The code in the file is as below:

```
.span-class {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: You have not imported you style.css file in your component file, try adding an import statement which will add style to your components.

Comment: You need to import the css file, like `import './style.css'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the style.css file to your index.js file.
If the style.css file has the same directory like index.js, you should add this

```
import './style.css'
```

to your index.js file

Answer (score 1):

Did you import the .css file in App.js?

Comment: .css file was not imported